# Using Jquery for each() on list item to output count

Tags: jquery, foreach

I have the following:

```
   <ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
<li>five</li>
<li>six</li>
</ul>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

I want output another list (#output) based on the number of lis.I can't wrapt my brain around exactly what to use. Am thinking it would be "count the number of lis in this ul, then for each, output the count/index into the #output div.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: jQuery Lerning Center: [Selecting elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) + [Manipulating elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing something like this:

```
$('#output').append('<ul>');
$('ul li').each(function(){
    $('#output ul').append('<li></li>');
});
$('#output').append('</ul>');
```

Obviously, adjusting it to however you need.
Also, you'll need an identifier on the original ul.

Comment: I want output another list (#output) based on the number of lis.....****Am thinking**** it would be "count the number of lis in this ul, then for each, output the count/index into the #output div.

Comment: can't get this to work, I see what you doing.. http://codepen.io/_Dawood/pen/GqXLAA?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the count of [li] you don't need each(), you can simply use .length property, in your case this statement return 6.

```
$('li').length;
```

So your script could be

```
$('#output').text($('li').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below snippet.

There are two way to find total number of li inside ul.

1. $("ul li").length;
2. $("ul li").size();

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($('ul li').length);
  alert($('ul li').size());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
</ul>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var n = $( "li" ).length;
  $( "div#output" ).text( "There are " + n + " list items" );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wgzwzgLc/6/

Comment: ok that makes, sense, but now for each one that exists in the original one, need to duplicate the li. so if there are 10 lis in the first one, it will duplicate an empty li list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the index of the current enumerator you can do .index($(this)) within your .each() function. For example:

```js
var tmpElementIndex = {};
var $listItems = $('ul li');

$listItems.each(function(){
   tmpElementIndex = $listItems.index($(this)) + 1;
   $('.other').append('<p>' + tmpElementIndex + ' of ' + $listItems.length + '</p>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>

<div class="other">
</div>
```

This can certainly be improved for better efficiency, but you get the idea.